# Getting Data Out of Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I apologize in advance for how rudimentary this question is, but how do I join strings that are nested in arrays within an array?

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do here is take a string and and capitalize the first letter of every word in the string.

Here the mess I have so far. Thanks for the help.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var a = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  var b = [];
  var c = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ];
  var d = [];
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b.push(a[i].split(''));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
      if (a[i][j] === a[i][0]) {
        c[i].push(a[i][j].toUpperCase());

      } else {
        c[i].push(a[i][j]);

      }


    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Give us an example of your data input and what you want as an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp is ideally suited for this job. Why don't you just do

```
var stc = "how to capitalize the first letter of each word in this sentence?",
  topic = stc.replace(/\b\w/g, m => m.toUpperCase()); // "How To Capitalize The First Letter Of Each Word In This Sentence?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this from a higher level and make use of two string features.

First, use `toUpperCase()` to capitalize the first letter, then use `String.prototype.slice()` to get the rest of the letters in each word.

The `slice(i)` string method just says "get me the characters in this string starting from position `i` and going until the end of the string." So `'hello world'.slice(1)` would be `'ello world'`, `'hello world'.slice(2)` would be `'llo world'`, and so on.

Here's an example:

```
var myWord = 'cRaZyCaSe';

var lower = myWord.toLowerCase();         // Make the whole word lower case
var firstLetter = lower[0].toUpperCase(); // Capitalize the first char
var rest = lower.slice(1);                // Get the rest of the word

console.log(firstLetter + rest);          // Add them back together
// -> 'Crazycase'
```

Your function could look like this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var thisWord = words[i].toLowerCase();
        words[i] = thisWord[0].toUpperCase() + thisWord.slice(1);
    }
    return words.join(' ');
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v74qdts8/)

Comment: Okay, and the last part of the iteration you're just concatenating the letter at 0 index with the rest of the word from index 1 to the end, right?

Comment: Exactly! `thisWord[0].toUpperCase()` gets the character at position 0 and makes it upper case and `thisWord.slice(1)` gets every character from position 1 forward. So added together, it's exactly what you said!